# PHP Regex: Remove text within parentheses in a span.class

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have something like:

```
<span class="product-title">title (description)</span>
```

and I want to remove with PHP the parentheses and its content of all `span.product-title`, to be like this:

```
<span class="product-title">title</span>
```

I successfully removed the text and the parentheses(`/\s\([^)]+\)/`), but I want to match only the content within `span.product-title`.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Don't use regexes on html. Use DOM to isolate that span, extract its text content, then deal with JUST that text string

Comment: To expand on @MarcB's comment, checkout [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`XPath`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) in PHP. An XPath query to retrieve the specific class would be `//span[@class="product-title"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All valid (and preferable) suggestions. However if you're simply looking for a quick & dirty regex fix, this should do:

```
/(<span class="product-title">.+?)\s*(?=\().+?\)(<\/span>)/i
```

replacing match with groups $1, $2 & $4.